# An Elegant Way to add Confrim Password field in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactive-programming

I have a project in which I have to add a registration form and I want to to validate that the password and confirm fields are equal without clicking the register button.

If password and confirm password field will not match, then I also want to put an error message at side of confirm password field and disable registration button.
I had these for handle password and username

```
const LoginForm = ({ register = false }) => {


const [isLoading, setLoading] = React.useState(false)
  const [errors, setErrors] = React.useState([])
  const [username, setUsername] = React.useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('')
  const handleUsernameChange = React.useCallback(
    (e) => setUsername(e.target.value),
    [setUsername]
  )
  const handleEmailChange = React.useCallback(
    (e) => setEmail(e.target.value),
    []
  )
  const handlePasswordChange = React.useCallback(
    (e) => setPassword(e.target.value),
    []
  )
```

and Got handle submit

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setLoading(true)
    try {
      let data, status
      if (register) {
        ;({ data, status } = await UserAPI.register(username, email, password))
      } else {
        ;({ data, status } = await UserAPI.login(email, password))
      }
      if (status !== 200 && data?.errors) {
        setErrors(data.errors)
      }
      if (data?.user) {
        // We fetch from /profiles/:username again because the return from /users/login above
        // does not contain the image placeholder.
        const { data: profileData, status: profileStatus } = await UserAPI.get(
          data.user.username
        )
        if (profileStatus !== 200) {
          setErrors(profileData.errors)
        }
        data.user.effectiveImage = profileData.profile.image
        window.localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(data.user))
        setCookie('auth', data.user.token)
        mutate('user', data.user)
        Router.push('/')
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    } finally {
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }
```

I want to add new confirm password field to this

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <fieldset>
          {register && (
            <fieldset className="form-group">
              <input
                className="form-control form-control-lg"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Username"
                value={username}
                onChange={handleUsernameChange}
              />
            </fieldset>
          )}
          <fieldset className="form-group">
            <input
              className="form-control form-control-lg"
              type="email"
              placeholder="Email"
              value={email}
              onChange={handleEmailChange}
            />
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset className="form-group">
            <input
              className="form-control form-control-lg"
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
              value={password}
              onChange={handlePasswordChange}
            />
          </fieldset>
          <button
            className="btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-xs-right"
            type="submit"
            disabled={isLoading}
          >
            {`${register ? 'Sign up' : 'Sign in'}`}
          </button>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
```

What is the most elegant way to add confirm password validation?

Comment: Just turn `password` into `password1` and `password2`, add another form field for `password2` and compare them in your component.

Answer (score 0):

The elegant way to create a form, in general, is using a form library. The form libraries will make your work easier, more elegant, and more developable. Most of them have a technique to use a function or a scheme as a validator that will help you certify your password.

The most popular form libraries currently are [Formik](https://formik.org/) and [React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com/) and if you are using Redux you can use [Redux Form](https://redux-form.com/).

In case you want to continue your current way of handling the form the best possible name for the second field is `passowrdConfirmation` is the best name in my Idea. Furthermore, you can create a validation function that you process before every field change(using a `useEffect` hook) or before submitting(using `onSubmit` event on form element).

Comment: That's awesome. I think I would use some library instead of my current way of handling the form

Comment: @AgentSP In that case, I prefer React Hook Form but Formik is more popular.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "useEffect" hook to listen to password and confirm password inputs.
Here is a simple example: https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-brook-tw15c

Comment: Woah Thanks for the advice. You are super helpful :D